# Dumpsys - How to identify power on/off

Tags: adb, power-on, shutdown, oppo, dumpsys

Is it possible to run a command in adb shell, dumpsys perhaps that will show the power on off dates and times from a year ago ?

I have run dumpsys and it has created a huge file with loads, 100's of thousands of records in a file - what text should I search for ?

I have tried searching for shutdown, power, reboot and some date strings when I know it was last turned off "2023-02-26 19" and "2023-02-26 20", and have found entries, but there is no textual description to say whether it is a power off of the phone for example:

package: com.oplus.atlas
Historical Process Exit for uid=1000
ApplicationExitInfo #0:
...
...

```
    ApplicationExitInfo #1:
      timestamp=**2023-02-26 20**:55:33.123
      pid=2930
      realUid=1000
      packageUid=1000
      definingUid=1000
      user=0
      process=com.oplus.persist.multimedia
      reason=13 (OTHER KILLS BY SYSTEM)
      subreason=3 (TOO MANY EMPTY PROCS)
      status=0
      importance=400
      pss=6.9MB
      rss=101MB
      description=empty #17
      state=empty
      trace=null
```